# Asp.Net Core 2 Web API 500 internal server error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

when I try to access the API via Postman,

Send:

> localhost:5050/api/Auth/token

Body:

> {     "UserName": "jouverc",  "Password": "P@ssw0rd!" }

to this method:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Auth")]
public class AuthController : Controller
{

    #region constructor injection

    private readonly IPasswordHasher<User> _hasher;
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
    private readonly IConfigurationRoot _config;
    private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;

    public AuthController(IPasswordHasher<User> hasher, UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager, IConfigurationRoot config)
    {
        _hasher = hasher;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _config = config;
    }

        #endregion

    #region createToken

    [HttpPost("token")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateToken([FromBody] CredentialModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName); 
            if (user != null) 
            {
                if (_hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, user.PasswordHash, model.Password) == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)  
                {
                    return Ok(CreateToken(user)); 
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //log 
        }
        return null;
    }

    private async Task<JwtPacket> CreateToken(User user)
    {
        var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user); 

        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName), 
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti,Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) 
        }.Union(userClaims);


        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"]));
        var cred = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256); 
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer: _config["Tokens:Issuer"], 
            audience: _config["Tokens:Audience"],
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(2),
            signingCredentials: cred
        );
        return new JwtPacket
        {
            Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
            Expiration = token.ValidTo.ToString(),
            UserName = user.UserName
        };

    }

    public class JwtPacket
    {
        public string Token;
        public string UserName;
        public string Expiration;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

I receive a 500 Internal Server Error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationRoot' while attempting to activate 'WebAPI.Controllers.AuthController

how should i configurate the Startup?

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change IConfigurationRoot to IConfiguration on the constructor for the controller.

But what might be better is to use the IOpions pattern for injecting settings into your controller.

Answer (score 2):

In .net core 2.0

`IConfigurationRoot` is now just `IConfiguration`.

Explained in this document: [Migrating from 1.x to 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/).

In `2.0` projects, the boilerplate configuration code inherent to `1.x` projects runs behind-the-scenes. For example, environment variables and app settings are loaded at startup. The equivalent `Startup.cs` code is reduced to `IConfiguration` initialization with the injected instance:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

Comment: as you said, but i dont know where is the problem. Is there something else I've missed, any idea?

Comment: The error says it cannot find the service from DI. You need to change the IConfigurationRoot to IConfiguration in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just reading values from the appsettings.json then use the IConfiguration interface instead.

Here's how to implement it in the Startup class

```
public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
}
```